# Volley priority doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-volley, priority-queue

I have to make two calls with volley. My problem is that I need to be done the first call and then the second. The calls are on a for loop. So I put on the first call `Priority.IMMEDIATE` and on the second `Priority.LOW`. But sometimes the second call is done before the first and I doesn't have the data that I need from the first call. What am I missing?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < SiteData.getSites().size(); i++) {
          firstCall();
          secondCall();
     }
```

the `firstCall` method

```
private void firstCall(){
    JsonObjectRequest siteDataRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // do something with json
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          VolleyLog.d(membership_id_tag, error.getMessage());
        }
    })

    {
       @Override
       public Priority getPriority() {
          return Priority.IMMEDIATE;
       }
    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(siteDataRequest, membership_id_tag);
}
```

the `secondCall` method

```
private void secondCall(){
    JsonArrayRequest pagesRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
          // do something with json
        }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(membership_page_tag, error.getMessage());
         }
      })

      {
          @Override
          public Priority getPriority() {
             return Priority.LOW;
          }
      };
      AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(pagesRequest, membership_page_tag);
}
```

Do I have to make the first call on a loop and the second on other?

Comment: Make the second call in the response of the first

Comment: hmm I see...I just wanted to avoid that because it will be too complex but it's the only way

Comment: I am not sure, but I have an hunch it might be because you are using 2 different request queue, json obj and json array hence priority might not  be working

Comment: @vasillis  did it work let me know

Comment: @war_Hero I have no clue. I will wait if it do it again. The problem is that the app crashes very rarely...

Comment: @war_Hero I think it's working...by the way if you want write it as answer to mark it as correct

Comment: Had the same issue. Instead of parsing the response in the onResponse() I overidded parseNetworkResponse and deliverResponse. Priority works correctly in this tweak. Did so because the above approach wasn't working everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the serving call in the response if the first, also the priority  might be happening because there are 2 different request queue that are being used.

Comment: I make the second call on the response of the first and now it's working :)